# Woocommerce - product images hidden on small screens

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I just noticed after Woocommerce update that the product image is hidden on small screens.

I can see that this is set in the file woocommerce-smallscreen.css but is it possible to override this in the theme custom css? Seems like I need to get rid of the float:none;
If I do this in the file woocommerce-smallscreen.css I guess it will be overwritten next time I update WooCommerce.

I tried but I am not sure that I got the custom css right.

This is what I see if I choose "inspect element" in chrome: media="only screen and (max-width: 768px)" .woocommerce #content div.product div.images, .woocommerce #content div.product div.summary, .woocommerce div.product div.images, .woocommerce div.product div.summary, .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images, .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.summary, .woocommerce-page div.product div.images, .woocommerce-page div.product div.summary {
float: none;
width: 100%;

If I unbox float:none; in chrome inspector, I can see the product photo. I tried to remove it from WooCommerce css-file but that didn't help.

Comment: try giving more details, providing some code - it would be easier for people to help. meanwhile, try to be more specific on your custom css https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: This is what I see if I choose "inspect element" in chrome:

media="only screen and (max-width: 768px)"
.woocommerce #content div.product div.images, .woocommerce #content div.product div.summary, .woocommerce div.product div.images, .woocommerce div.product div.summary, .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images, .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.summary, .woocommerce-page div.product div.images, .woocommerce-page div.product div.summary {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;

Comment: If I unbox float:none; in chrome inspector, I can see the product photo. I tried to remove it from WooCommerce css-file but that didn't help.

Comment: I would not suggest removing that, since there are multiple elements affected by it. Without mode detailed code (html,css,javascript - or maybe the website itself) is not easy to give you a proper solution...

Comment: Sorry about the lack in information, I am still trying to figure out how this works ;)
Example url: [link](https://www.dogonleash.ca/shop/all-pearl-shiny-bl/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `float:left` to the element containing the image

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery.woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-4.images {
    float: left;
}
```

if it's not working, try adding the `!important` rule

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery.woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images.woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-4.images {
    float: left !important;
}
```